# Best practice for temporary entities in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm looking for a 'best practice' to deal with temporary entities.  My app creates a bunch of entities as a result of a calculation, and I show them in a `UITableView` using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. The user can then decide to save the results to the store, or discard them. When saved the results can be easily retrieved at a later time without redoing the calculations.

I see a few possibilities:

1. Create the entities during the calculation and only save the context when user decides to do so. If not, delete all the entities from the context.
2. Create the entities but don't use a context, but then I cannot show them using my FRC.
3. Don't create entities, but dummy objects, and only convert them to entities when the user selects save.

Since option 2 is not going to work, any thoughts on using either option 1 or 3 ? Maybe a missed another option?

Comment: 4. Always save them and perform cleanup when needed based on the special property value. 5. Use three contexts: persistent, temporal and merged, show the data from the latter using FRC.

Comment: Personally I prefer to store entity attributes (not an entity) temporarily as private variables for the life of the TVC, and save only if and when the user specifically taps a save button... but that is my preference based on my UI and app structure.

Comment: You can create a separate context, potentially a child context, rather than having to maintain a collection of all the ephemeral objects yourself.