# Core data relationship nil after fetching

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is a follow up question to [Best practice for temporary entities in core data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327021/best-practice-for-temporary-entities-in-core-data). I made a new topic, since I think this is a different issue.

When I setup my temp entities in a child context, I make a relationship with an entity that is already in the store. This works with no errors, using the objectID to pass the entity accross threads.  I used breakpoints to verify that the relationship is ok.

Now when I get to the table to display all the temp objects (using an `NSFetchedResultsController`), the relationship is nil. All other attributes of the temp object are in place, just not the relationship.

So I am surely missing something here.

Here's some code I tried:

```
Temp *temp = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Temp" inManagedObjectContext: myImportContext];

NSManagedObjectID *objectID = self.test.objectID;

if (objectID)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    Test *t = (Test *)[myImportContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error: &error];

    if (error == nil)
        [temp addTestObject: t];
}
```

UPDATE: I forgot to add that all this is running on a background thread.

UPDATE 2: I figured out the problem. The relationship between Temp and Test was a one to many, so everytime I added a Test object to a Temp, it deleted the relationship between the previous Temp and Test. Setting the relationship to many to many solved it.

Comment: As I understand it, your child context will not persist to the data store until you call a save on that context and perhaps (depending on your structure) a save on the parent context. Do you save your context/s before you attempt to call your `NSFetchedResultsController`? Also I can highly recommend this text - from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra.

Comment: That is correct, my entities are temp, so I am not persisting them to the store until the user wants to save them. And that is no problem for the `NSFetchedResultsController`, since I'm using the child context for that. The table loads fine with all the info about the temp entities, except for the relationships which are nil. I have Zarra's book as well as the one by Tim Roadley. I will keep digging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  The relationship between Temp and Test was a one to many, so everytime I added a Test object to a Temp, it deleted the relationship between the previous Temp and Test. Setting the relationship to many to many solved it.